# append value from loop linear regression in a certain position in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append values from linear regression in a rolling window. The storable values are supposed to be appended in a certain position of my df (i.e. having a df 2300 x 2300, the first value from regression should be in the first col at 228th row and so on so forth).

Here below is my code.

Any help is more than welcome.

df_rolling_tstat # 2300 x 2300 dataframe

```
for i in range(len(Switz_fund_ret.iloc[1:, 1:2].columns)):
    s = Switz_fund_ret.loc[birth_date[i], :]
    start = s['contatore']
    e = Switz_fund_ret.loc[death_date[i], :]
    end = e['contatore']
    window = 12

    for j in range(end-start):


        roll_one = Switz_fund_ret[i].iloc[start+j:start+window+j]
        #market excess return del mercato quando il fondo era in attività
        roll_two = Switz_fund_ret[2308].iloc[start+j:start+window+j] 
        #risk free rate quando il fondo era in attività
        roll_three = Switz_fund_ret[2309].iloc[start+j:start+window+j]
        roll_excess_return_fund = roll_one - roll_three 
        roll_two = sm.add_constant(roll_two)
        roll_y=np.array(roll_excess_return_fund, dtype=float)
        roll_x=np.array(roll_two, dtype=float)

        roll_model = sm.OLS(roll_y, roll_x).fit()
        roll_reg.append(roll_model)
        alpha_roll.append(roll_model.params[0])
        t_stat_roll.append(roll_model.tvalues[0])
        p_value_roll.append(roll_model.pvalues[0])
```

I would like, for instance, to retrieve roll_model.pvalues[0] and put it in the first column of df at 228th position. Afterward, for the 2nd regression, I want to store roll_model.pvalues[0] at 229th entry.

Many thanks.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifcally? Can you share a [mcve]? Also, it's probably best to add the data to a temporary data structure and then use that to create the DataFrame.

Comment: hello AMC, I m struggling to append the result for each regression in the specific position (ie. first col, row 228 for the first parameters)

Comment: Appending a value to a single column is a bit awkward, you should try just building a list of the results.

Comment: I see what you mean...so in this case, I create my list but who can i insert in in a specific position in my df? I made myself more cleare, I have my list and I want to put all the values in list in my first column starting from row 228th. So the next time i run regression i will put the next column in column 2 in my data frame in position 228th

Comment: _I have my list and I want to put all the values in list in my first column starting from row 228th._ You have a list, and you want to add the elements to (row, col) (228, 1), (229, 1), etc. ? Am I understanding that correctly? _So the next time i run regression i will put the next column in column 2 in my data frame in position 228th_ You could always combine the lists for each column, right?

Comment: yes, you understood correctly!